# Looking for comprehensive list of Partikeln

Tags: particle

My Duden assigns the category "Partikel" to the following words (or to one of their possible meanings/usages), among others:

> aber, auch, eben, eigentlich, erst, gefälligst, ja, mal, recht, schon, selbst, sogar, überhaupt

I'm looking for a comprehensive listing of such Partikeln.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Keine Garantie auf Vollständigkeit, aber schau mal auf [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/index.html?MenuId=Word54)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a list in the german wikipedia:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikel_%28Grammatik%29
(This list has Duden as it's source...)

There's also a definition (kind of) in the grimmsche Wörterbuch for Partikel and some further (historic) references:
http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=partikel
It is a little bit hard to read due to old language.

Hope this helps.